# Why is "they" written “S'ils”?

Tags: conjonctions, conditions

I came about the following sentence:

> S'ils ne sont pas d'accord sur cet ordre …

Does "S'ils" mean "they"? What words is it composed of?

Answer (score 4):

*S'ils* is the contraction of *Si* and *ils*.

> If they do not agree …